# Neo4J java REST API - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, rest, neo4j

I have made a simple java Servlet that needs to communicate with a Neo4J server using REST API.
I'm using the following library: neo4j-rest-graphdb-2.0.1.jar.

The only line I have written so far is

```
RestAPI graphDb = new RestAPIFacade("http://localhost:7474/db/data");
```

Unfortunately every time I start the servlet I get this error:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [servlets.ServletFrontend] in context with path [/ServletTest] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestAPI
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
    at servlets.ServletFrontend.doPost(ServletFrontend.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm using Eclipse and I've already imported that library (and org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestAPI is in there).

What am I missing?

Comment: You didn't specify how you packaged your project and how you deployed it, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer your questions.
I've manually added the library form the project config in Ecipse (no maven). I'm using Tomcat v8.0

Comment: You probably didn't package the library (and all its dependencies) when you create the war for Tomcat.

Comment: Thank you so much!
It's the first time I'm working with Tomcat and I didn't know I had to select the libraries I wanted to deploy... I was pretty confident Ecipse would have handled that automatically.

In the meantime, I've managed to use Maven. It really simplifies the job!

Thank you again!